# XQuery expression with predicates

Tags: xquery, predicates

I'm trying to use an expression with a predicate to display the child nodes for each parent node (the exercise looks silly because this is test data: the final solution has to draw in data from other xml files).

A sample of the data is as follows:

```
<Schools>
<School>
<name>St John's</name>
<AcademicYear year = "2017"></AcademicYear>
<Subject>English</Subject>
<Subject>Geography</Subject>
<Subject>Maths</Subject>
<AcademicYear year = "2016"></AcademicYear>
<Subject>Maths</Subject>
<Subject>Textiles</Subject>
<Subject>English</Subject>
<AcademicYear year = "2015"></AcademicYear>
<Subject>History</Subject>
<Subject>French</Subject>
<Subject>Spanish</Subject>
</School>

<School>
<name>Marsh Academy</name>
<AcademicYear year = "2017"></AcademicYear>
<Subject>Science</Subject>
<Subject>Geography</Subject>
<Subject>Computer science</Subject>
<AcademicYear year = "2016"></AcademicYear>
<Subject>English</Subject>
<Subject>History</Subject>
<Subject>Maths</Subject>
<AcademicYear year = "2015"></AcademicYear>
<Subject>French</Subject>
<Subject>Geography</Subject>
<Subject>Art</Subject>
</School>

</Schools>
```

The query is below:

```
<Schools>
{for $School in doc("test.xml")/Schools/School
return
<School>
  <Name>
  {$School/name}
  </Name>
  {for $i in doc("test.xml")/Schools/[School = $School]/AcademicYear
  return
  <AcademicYear>
    {$i/@year}
    <subject><teacher></teacher><scale></scale></subject>
  </AcademicYear>}
   </School>}
</Schools>
```

The error appears says "node expected, array found" in relation to line 8. I've tried both a for loop, and simply placing an expression  inside the academic year tags as follows

> {doc("test.xml")/Schools/[School = $School]/AcademicYear/@year}

Sorry - I'm sure it is simple. I'm a beginner!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no child node preceding the predicate.

When selecting the `School` elements, move it outside of the predicate as the child node selected from the `Schools` element, and then inside the predicate filter, refer to the current `School` element with `.`:

```
for $i in doc("test.xml")/Schools/School[. = $School]/AcademicYear
```

But if you are iterating over the elements from the same document, why not just use the already selected `$School`:

```
for $i in $School/AcademicYear
```

Comment: Many thanks - that's really helpful. I hadn't understood the role of the context item expressive. I've now looked it up! Thank you.